# why doesn't visual studio code class attribute work?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm new in VSC and trying to use class attribute but it doesn't autofill. when I try to write it manually it does nothing. what can I do?

Comment: Try the extension "CSS Peek" or "css-class-intellisense".  I can't remember which one of those does it.  It isn't built-in, you will need an extension.  There probably are other extensions that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you were looking for:

You can try to install some HTML extensions like **HTML Snippets** (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abusaidm.html-snippets), or **HTML CSS Support** (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css).

There are a lot of extensions in VSCode to autofill attributes.

Answer (score -1):

create new folder and project and import in visual code this new project and folder, and restarting visual